# Is there a way in JetBrains IDE's to set a keyboard shortcut to move the caret/cursor to the center?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am looking for a command in JetBrains IDE's (specifically WebStorm and Rider) to set a keyboard shortcut that will center the caret in the center of the editor page.

Is this possible with a shortcut or extension?

Just to be clear, I don't want to move the page to center the caret (which already exists with s shortcut), I want to move the caret to the center of the page, without moving the editor page view.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to better demonstrate the desired feature?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this???

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: There is "Scroll to Center" action (the one you must be referring to), but nothing like "Move Caret to Center". What are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe there are better tools/plugins for that...

Comment: I am trying to achieve moving my caret to the center.

Comment: What benefits it will provide when the caret is in the center of the screen? Or is it "I wanted it for my own reasons"?

Comment: Because generally I like the code I am editing to be in the center of the screen. So I press ctrl+down to scroll the view to where I want to edit, then I want to center the caret to the view to being editing.

Comment: It's not the same ofc, but what about AceJump or alike plugin -- that allows to quickly move your caret to a certain position on a screen with just a few keys. Will that be any good?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just use `Ctrl + M` to move the caret to centre of the screen.

If you don't want to have to hit `Ctrl + M` all the time, you can also achieve what you want by using the `IdeaVim` plugin

1. Open the Settings dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. Select Plugins.
3. Find the `IdeaVim` plugin and install.

[image: ideavim]

4. Create `$HOME/.ideavimrc`
5. Add `set scrolloff=XX` where `XX` is at least half the total lines you would usually see. Setting 'scrolloff' to a large value causes the cursor to stay in the middle line when possible. e.g. `set scrolloff=999`
6. Restart your IDE.

Tested and working in PHPStorm and PyCharm

Comment: This is not an adequate answer, as the number of lines shown can change depending on view size, so a fixed value would not work.

Comment: @Scorb - So why doesn't  `Ctrl + M`  work as I suggested first? Also you can just Setting 'scrolloff' to a large value causes the cursor to stay in the middle line when possible. e.g. `set scrolloff=999` see my edit.

Comment: @Scorb The scrolloff setting is the desired number of lines above and below the caret, so setting a large fixed value, e.g. `999` - would absolutely work all on all view sizes. Have you even tried it?